Getting 302 Found on hitting a spring boot service which is secured by Azure B2C
I am not sure why I am getting 302 Found but no Response body. When I try to hit a spring-boot service secured by Azure b2c using Postman, I am correctly passing the access token I generated from this function
@GetMapping("/token")
    public String getAccessToken(Authentication authentication) {
        if (authentication instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken) {
            String clientRegistrationId = oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();
            OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
                    clientRegistrationId, oauthToken.getName());

            if (client != null) {
                OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = client.getAccessToken();
                return "Access Token: " + accessToken.getTokenValue();
            }
        }
        return "Access token not found!";
    }

On decoding this token with jwt.io, Getting this
"iss": "https://learningakash.b2clogin.com/a593b6b3-b245-4e93-9213-e5e9c70a25ec/v2.0/",
  "exp": 1728976728,
  "nbf": 1728973128,
  "sub": "e7433b04-2a76-44d2-bc58-0c6844068546",
  "given_name": "Piggy",
  "family_name": "Account",
  "tfp": "B2C_1_signupsignin",
  "nonce": "pkAg9R-R2x6RodQUfbT8LZzJd6fzm9-ulN9xS-OFvoY",
  "azp": "77a7047b-ec7f-4d87-bad7-d2d145425a57",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iat": 1728973128
}

Strange part is that JWT.io is showing invalid signature like this,

What am I doing wrong here.

Sounds like the API might configured incorrectly. An API should not be returning 302 responses. It should be a 401 or 403 if it considers the token invalid or a lack of permissions. It might be configured with interactive authentication instead of JWT authentication. Jwt.io showing invalid signature is due to you not providing it the public key on the right side. It can't guess the verification key. We can assume the signature is fine.

@juunas what could be the possible solution then. Is it something I have to do in azure b2c portal.

@DasariKamali Thanks. Can you figure out from my question above, why my postman is giving 302 Found with no response body even if I am providing the correct access token to it? Also want to let you know I am able to access the get request from my browser after authorization.

@AkashVerma Can you share your application.properties in the question?

@AkashVerma Have you added the scope in the Azure AD B2c app?

@DasariKamali Do you mean the "Expose an API" option? If yes that I haven't done. If that is important, can you explain to me why that is important to execute the API in Postman while it is working in browser windows. Sorry if that's a silly question, I am new to azure.

@AkashVerma Yes, Expose an API. Can you add that scope and try again by adding it to your scope in application.proprties

@DasariKamali Added scope, but still no luck {
"alg": "RS256",
"kid": "X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk",
"typ": "JWT"
}.{
"aud": "77a7047b-ec7f-4d87-bad7-d2d145425a57",
"iss": "https://learningakash.b2clogin.com/a593b6b3-b245-4e93-9213-e5e9c70a25ec/v2.0/",
"exp": 1729064259,
"nbf": 1729060659,
"sub": "e7433b04-2a76-44d2-bc58-0c6844068546",
"given_name": "Piggy",
"family_name": "Account",
"tfp": "B2C_1_signupsignin",
"scp": "transaction.read",
"azp": "77a7047b-ec7f-4d87-bad7-d2d145425a57",
"ver": "1.0",
"iat": 1729060659
}.[Signature]

I tried adding the access token to the jwt.io and got the same error Invalid Signature, because I used the access token in RS256 Algorithm.
For reference check this SO Answer.
JWT.io doesnot support RS256.
Initially, I was also getting same error when using RS256 but when I change to HS265 it worked for me.


